# how to install Kyma in local k3s cluster not inside k3d?

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, k3d, kyma

Following the local [install guide for Kyma](https://kyma-project.io/#/02-get-started/01-quick-install) , I have setup a kyma cluster inside k3d, so the entire kubernetes cluster is basically running within a docker container.

This is where I'm at right now

Host Machine -> k3d (docker container) -> k3s -> kyma runtime

This is where I want to be

Host Machine -> k3s -> kyma runtime

How do I set up the kyma runtime on k3s without using k3d? Thanks

I've tried installing kyma runtime using k3d and it works.
Now I want to install it without using k3d.